# Jquery append problem

Tags: jquery

So I have a bunch of `<li>`'s in a grid format. I have some jquery setup to allow you to hover over the li and a set of buttons show up over the li with some different options. I had the jquery working fine untill i moved the hover selector from an element that was with in `<li>` to the whole `<li>`. Now it seems that when I try to append my buttons to the li to particular element it dosent work, it seems to append to every `<li>` not just the one I am hovering on.note i was trying to use this for appending and this didnt work either nothing happen instead:

```
$.tmpl(quickbuttonTemplate).appendTo($(this).closest('.details');
```

so that way I didnt get any results so I went with this and this is where I was having it append to every li instead of  just the one i was hovering on:

```
function quickView() {
    var quickbuttonTemplate = $('#quick-button-template').template();
    var quicklightTemplate = $('#quick-view-template').template();
    // Grid Hover Overlays
    $('.grid li').live('mouseover', function () {
        if (!$(this).data('init')) {
            $(this).data('init', true);
            $(this).hoverIntent(

            function () {
                $.tmpl(quickbuttonTemplate).appendTo($('.details'));
                $('.quick-container').css({
                    'width': $('.grid li').width() + "px",
                    'height': ($('.grid li').height() - 56) + "px"
                }).show();
            },

            function () {
                $('.quick-container').remove();
            });
            $(this).trigger('mouseover');
            interval: 20
        }
    });
```

Here is my html:

```
    <li data="{ id: Some number }">
    <div class="header">
        <h4><a href="/some url" title="some text">Header name</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <div class="photo">
            <a href="some url" title="some text"><img src="some image" alt="some text"></a>

        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="some url" title="some text">
                <img src="/some url" width="50" height="25" alt="some text" title="some text">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="pricing clearfix">
            <span class="price">some price</span>
        </div>                                                
    </div>
    <div class="rating clearfix">
        <a href="some url" title="some text"><div class="rating-4" onclick="window.location='some url"></div></a>
        <a href="some url" title="some text" class="rating-count countLeft">29</a>                                       
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: If you show us the markup maybe...

Comment: The main question is why Is my line that says :<code>$.tmpl(quickbuttonTemplate).appendTo($('.details'));</code> not appending

Comment: I have put up the mark up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this:

```
$.tmpl(quickbuttonTemplate).appendTo($(this).closest('.details');
```

doesn't work b/c closest looks UP the down tree, you want to look inside of $(this)...

closest documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/closest/

you can use .find

```
$.tmpl(quickbuttonTemplate).appendTo($(this).find('.details');
```

also:  if your using $(this) in more then one line, like you are,  it's best to store it in a local variable.   ie:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Comment: Thank you very munch Patricia, you have been very helpful. I will mark this as answered in a minute. Thank you again